# How to get rid of vboxnet0 NIC from command line on Windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox

I have a virtual machine created by vagrant on Ubuntu 14.04 (VirtualBox 5.0.10). It has two NICs. NIC1 is NAT, NIC2 is hostonly. 
After importing that machine to VirtualBox 5.1.8 on Windows 10 I cannot run it as VBox complains that **vboxnet0 (adapter 2)** cannot be found.
If I show VM info in command line at this point (`VBoxManage showvminfo "myvm"`) NIC2 says:

> Attachment: Host-only Interface 'vboxnet0'

.

I found a workaround: disable NIC2 in VBox GUI and then enable it again. If I do this and run showvminfo again then NIC2 says:

> Attachment: Host-only Interface 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet
>   Adapter'

and machine will boot.

I'm looking for a way to automate this from command line. I tried to do this:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "myvm" --nic2 none
VBoxManage modifyvm "myvm" --nic2 hostonly
```

but then it sets back 'vboxnet0'.
How to force it to set proper Windows hostonly adapter from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "myvm" --hostonlyadapter2 "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"
```